Podam can't handle java.nio.ByteBuffer field
I generate some objects using Podam library, but there is a field, podam can't handle.
private java.nio.ByteBuffer valueBase64;

When I try to create object from the class, it takes very long and most likely end with something like java heap insufficient memory error.
public <T> T createObject(Class<?> clazz) {
    PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
    podamFactory.getStrategy().addOrReplaceTypeManufacturer(List.class, (strategy, attributeMetadata, genericTypesArgumentsMap) -> Collections.emptyList());
    Object o = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(clazz);
    return (T) o;
}

Printed result looks like this:
, ... "contentDataForTemplate": {"valueBase64": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000... etc.

It clearly adds to the buffer until memory runs out.
Is there a way how to tell it to:

Put a concrete value to this particular field
Simply ignore java.nio.ByteBuffer type?

I know I could use @PodamExclude annotation over this field, but those classes are AVRO generated, therefore I can't simply put annotation on anything. All configuration must be done outside. And this exclude only excludes certain attributes, not data types.

Ok, any explanation why someone suggested closing?

Ok, I figured it out.
        podamFactory.getStrategy().addOrReplaceTypeManufacturer(java.nio.ByteBuffer.class, (strategy, attributeMetadata, genericTypesArgumentsMap) -> java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(10));

